# bootstrap split button dropdown item value undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-state

I'm not used to playing with split button values in react bootstrap but i'm just trying to update my react state with the value of a splitbutton but the value always returns undefined... Not sure what I'm doing wrong? I have a value property for all my dropdown items in place already.

```
handleChange=(e)=>{
    this.setState({[e.name]: e.target.value})
    console.log(e.target.value)
}

<SplitButton className="dropdownItem" variant='Secondary' title='step pattern'>
      <Dropdown.Item onClick={this.handleChange} name='stepPattern'  eventKey="1" value='step' ><img className="patterns" alt="a stepped gradient" src={step}></img></Dropdown.Item>
      <Dropdown.Divider />
      <Dropdown.Item onClick={this.handleChange} name='stepPattern' eventKey="2" value='wave' ><img className="patterns" alt="a wavy gradient" src={wave}></img></Dropdown.Item>
       <Dropdown.Divider />
       <Dropdown.Item onClick={this.handleChange} name='stepPattern'  eventKey="3" value='curve' ><img className="patterns" alt="an upward sloped gradient" src={curve}></img></Dropdown.Item>     
       </SplitButton>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using handleChange (which I suggest), you could change it in the following way:

```
handleChange = value => {
    this.setState({ stepPattern: value });
    console.log(value);
}
```

By doing this, now all you need is your Dropdown.Item to call the handleChange function. Try the following:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <SplitButton className="dropdownItem" variant='secondary' title='step pattern' >
        <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => { this.handleChange(1); }} eventKey="1" value='step' ><img className="patterns" alt="a stepped gradient" src={step}></img></Dropdown.Item>
        <Dropdown.Divider />
        <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => { this.handleChange(2); }} eventKey="2" value='wave' ><img className="patterns" alt="a wavy gradient" src={wave}></img></Dropdown.Item>
        <Dropdown.Divider />
        <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => { this.handleChange(3); }} eventKey="3" value='curve' ><img className="patterns" alt="an upward sloped gradient" src={curve}></img></Dropdown.Item>
      </SplitButton >
    );
  }
```

Now each of the buttons is calling the function with predefined value, which can be taken out in constants.